# ANDROID_HOME - cordova ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, cordova

при запуске

> sudo cordova emulate android

```
alexey@alexey-System:~/Projects/opa$ sudo cordova emulate android
Running command: /home/alexey/Projects/opa/platforms/android/cordova/run --emulator

    ERROR: Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.
    Error: /home/alexey/Projects/opa/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2
        at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
        at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
        at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5
```

несколько дней искал решение проблемы, прописывал в .bashrc и .profile, успехом это так не кончилось:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk-linux
PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Надеюсь на помощь.

Comment: Вы уверены, что нужно запускать через sudo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запускайте без *sudo*, эмулятору не нужны права root.

Если совсем не получается (чего, в принципе, не должно быть), то попробуйте запускать `sudo -l` чтобы загрузился *.profile* пользователя root, либо `sudo -E`, чтобы сохранить текущие переменные окружения.

Comment: Большое спасибо, за три дня пятиминутный рывок) sudo -E подошел как вариант